# Looking for a graphical dialog program that I can use for my bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, dd, zenity

I am trying to write a DD frontend in bash, and I was looking for a simple to use dialog program. I have used things like `zenity` before, but it was not complex enough for my needs. All I need is some text, a file selection, a disk selection and a start and quit button. As far as I know `zenity` can do all these things, but only in a single window at a time. Is there some utility I can use to create this?

Comment: The tool **`yad`** is more powerful than `zenity`.

See the accepted answer at this link, https://askubuntu.com/questions/31172/need-an-interface-for-a-gui-shell-script-more-powerful-than-zenity. But you can do a lot with `zenity` too, See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/ and try `mkusb`.

Comment: What's `DD`? Do you mean `dd`?

Comment: @terdon yes, dd.

Answer (score 2):

**Have you tried [`dialog`](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) (or its cut-down Debian variant [`whiptail`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/whiptail))?**

I know it is *not really graphical*; and I don't have experience about its flexibility either. But it is apparently flexible enough that **GNU/Linux distributions' installers *actually use this*** as their user-facing front.

(If you have used distros' text mode installer, you won't forget this program's signature appearance— *blue background with gray windows and red progress bar*)